# Sequel query with join and condition on the other table

Tags: ruby, sequel

I'm pretty new to Sequel and I'm scratching my head trying to figure out how to get Sequel's API to generate the following trivial SQL:

```
          select f.* from first f
          join second s on f.second_id = s.id
          where s.deactivated = false
```

The best I could come up with is:

```
      First.join(:second, deactivated: false, id: :second_id)
        .paged_each do |first|
          # magic happens here
        end
```

But that does `select *` not `select first.*` and as a result gets confused about what `id` to order by for paging and throws `PG::AmbiguousColumn: ERROR:  ORDER BY "id" is ambiguous`

This is using Sequel 5.9.0 and Postres 10.

## Solution

Thanks to @engineersmnky's suggestion about `qualify` and some further reading here's the approach I ended up using.

```
      First.join(:second, id: :second_id, deactivated: false)
        .qualify
        .stream.each do |first|
          # magic happens here
        end
```

The `qualify` method call resolves the ambiguity (and ensures only first table gets returned.

I also added `sequel_pg` gem so I can use `stream.each` rather than `paged_each`. This has a better performance but also removes the need for the `order by id` that was causing me grief initially.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Disclaimer: I have never actually used `sequel`**

There appears to be a method [`Sequel::Dataset#qualify`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/jeremyevans/sequel/Sequel%2FDataset:qualify) that will do exactly what you are asking and should result in:

```
select first.* from first 
  join second on first.second_id = second.id
  where second.deactivated = false
```

I think the implementation would look like:

```
First.join(:second, id: :second_id)
    .where(Sequel[:second][:deactivated] => false) 
    #OR .where("second.deactivated": false)
    #OR .where{[[second[:deactivated],false]]}
    .qualify
    .paged_each do |first|
      # magic happens here
    end
```

Now if `First` and `Second` are properly associated `Sequel::Model`s it appears the join condition can be inferred through `association_join` [See Here from the docs](https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel#joining-with-associations) e.g.

```
First.association_join(:second)
    .where(Sequel[:second][:deactivated] => false)
    .qualify
    .paged_each do |first|
      # magic happens here
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Disclosure

Not an Sequel expert. But I do use it.

I think `where` statements that come after joins are NOT `virtual rows`. You'd have to qualify them in some way - here's one way - and there are probably other ways too:

#### Solution

```
DB[:F].join(:S, id: :second_id).where(Sequel[:S][:deactivated] => false).sql
```

##### SQL produced:

SELECT * FROM F INNER JOIN S ON (S.id = F.second_id) WHERE (S.deactivated IS FALSE)

#### To Check:

1. Clone the Sequel Gem: https://github.com/jeremyevans/sequel
2. Run the following command in the root directory of the gem:

`bin/sequel -c "puts DB[:F].join(:S, id: :second_id).where(Sequel[:S][:deactivated] => false).sql"`